# All text except footnotes disappeared in Word 2010 document

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2019

I’ve been working on a book that is (was) approaching 60,000 words. Then one day I opened the file and this is what I found…no body text or images, only the footnotes all grouped together at the bottom of two pages.

[screeenshot of footnote text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSy3L.png)

It seems that the text must be there somewhere, because:

1. Although Word Count shows 1258 (the number of words in the footnotes), the file size is still the same as the old almost 60,000-word file (2649 K). To prove this, I saved a new file with just the footnote text, and it’s only 19K.
2. The Navigation/Find pane still lists all of my Heading formatted text.

What I’ve tried:

All of the Views, turning computer off/on, saving in a .doc format, tried to recover an older version, tried to Compare previous drafts.
Any thoughts will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: A sample file with the problem would help with troubleshooting. Here is my article on the Microsoft site telling why and how to do this. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_365hp/why-a-sample-file-is-important-for-troubleshooting/9441ae3c-1e92-41c6-9a1f-5b377b08e5a5?tm=1619027698258

Comment: Charles: I read the article but am not clear on how I can get my file uploaded to this site or to you.

Comment: Briefly, save a sample file with the problem in DropBox or OneDrive and post a view link here. The page has additional information on how to remove confidential/proprietary content.

Comment: Are you working in Word 2019 on a document generated by Word 2010? How are you coming with the sample document?